# any good param to build my map?

Tags: navigation, mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im working on gazebo simulator , i have created my world sdf file and lunch file , but when i build the map of y world i got bad map not similar to my world ( not accurate map ) , although i played with the param but i still facing the same problem . any one has a good param i can use?
thnaks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189302/any-good-param-to-build-my-map?/) by [haider](https://answers.ros.org/users/18016/haider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-07**:
How did you build your map gmapping or hector mapping ? Better share your map build so far, for better info.

**Comment by [haider](https://answers.ros.org/users/18016/haider/) on 2014-08-07**:
i used gmapping demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It all depends on the computational power of your computer. If you have a fast computer, you can set your mapping parameters to lets say, higher resolution, larger map area, as well as update rate. If you are working on a arduino or a embedded system, you wont be able to set those parameters high because it will slow down the rest of your system.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-07**:
as @bvbdort asked, please post your current parameters.

**Comment by [haider](https://answers.ros.org/users/18016/haider/) on 2014-08-16**:
@bvbdort , @l0g1x can you tell what file shall i share with you ? , because im new in ros , by the way the power of my computer is very high

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-16**:
you can see the parameters for gmapping in launch file. Here is descriptions about [gmapping parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping#Parameters)